# TFS Sonar Integration - .dll missing error

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube

Working on TFS Sonar integration which are on same box with sample console app and a single unit test method .

When I run TFS build with all necessary parameters I m able to see output in Sonar and build fails with .dll missing error

Options tried : Registed .dll to TFS 2015 Build Controller 
Added all nuget packages

[image: XAML Build output with missing DLL Error]

Comment: The DLL that is missing is usually part of Visual Studio 2015, do you have this installed on the build server?

Comment: Since you are using TFS 2015, we suggest you use the new build system instead of old xaml build.

Comment: @DaveShaw - Thanks for your reply. Yes I have VS 2015 TFS 2015 & Sonar on same box. begin command works fine, but end throws - dll missing error .

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - I tried with VNEXT and I ended up with The C# plugin installed on the SonarQube server is not compatible the SonarQube analysis agent (i.e. the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe, or the build automation task). Either check the compatibility matrix or get the latest versions for both.

Comment: Just an update - Though the build fails with an error I can see Sonar dashboard gets updated with right values. CmD line execution of 'end' works with no issues

Comment: If you are using TFS2015, try installing the TFS2013 Object Model as described in the SonarQube docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2013

Comment: @user2153844 Did you follow the steps in article below https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services when you use vNext build?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Hey Yes ! Sonar - begin step works good ! But end throws missing dll error . :(

Comment: I m not using VNext I m using XAML , Sonar begin works great, but end throws below error  Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.BuildSummaryLogger.WriteMessage(String message, Object[] args)
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.SummaryReportBuilder.Up

Comment: All - It worked with customizing my build template . All I did was instead of calling Sonar 'End; in post arguments . I wrote a simple batch file and called withing template with  "Invoke Process" after get impacted steps. Thanks all for your inputs !